# Append all stock.move ID's to list from all chain of related records

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have records in the `stock.move` table that has `One2many` relation to `stock.move.reconcile` with column `move_to_id` which is the ID of another record in `stock.move` table. So this chain can be thousands of records.

As you can see in my example I loop trough all records and go down tier by tier, but as I said before there could be thousands of linked records so my approach will not work here.

I do know that probably I need to use a `while` loop here, something like `while there is move_to_ids`, then I should loop through records and keep adding IDs to list, but I just can't figure it out how to do it.

- `move1(stock.move ID = 10)` record that has `One2many` relation with 2 records inside: `move_to_ids` (`stock.move.reconcile`)
- each of `move_to_ids` has `move_to_id(many2one, 'stock.move' ID = 11)`
- each of this `move_to_id(stock.move, ID=11)` records have again any number of `move_to_ids (`stock.move.reconcile`) and each of this`move_to_ids`records have`move_to_id('stock.move', ID=12)` and so on.

So basically I want to add to list all `move_to_id` IDs 10, 11, 12, etc. to list for all related `move_to_ids`.

`moves_to_recalculate = [10,11,12]` and so on until when there is 0 `move_to_ids` to get `move_to_id` from.

```py
class StockMove(models.Model):
_name = 'stock.move'

move_to_ids = fields.One2many(
    'stock.move.reconcile', 'move_from_id', string='Move to')

 move_from_ids = fields.One2many(
    'stock.move.reconcile', 'move_to_id', string='Move From'
)
```

```py
class StockMoveReconcile(models.Model):
    _name = 'stock.move.reconcile'
    _description = 'Stock Move Reconcile'

    move_to_id = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string='Move To')
    move_from_id = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string='Move From')

def recalculate(self):
    moves = self.browse(('active_ids'))
    moves_to_recalculate = []
    for move1 in moves:
        #I add my first move in chain to list
        moves_to_recalculate.append(move1.id)
        #First move have 2 moves_to_ids so i make another loop to add it ID to list
        for second_tier_move in move.move_to_ids:
            moves_to_recalculate.appen(second_tier_move.move_to_id.id)
            # secont tier move has 1 move_to_ids so i do another loop, and add it's ID to list.
            for third_tier_move in second_tier_move.move_to_ids:
                moves_to_recalculate.appen(third_tier_move.move_to_id.id)
                #third_tier_move has another move_to_ids , and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from other resource but I think i need to post it here because the answer is excellent.

```py
def recalculate_fifo(self):

    moves = self.browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))
    moves_to_recalculate = moves
    current_moves = moves
    while current_moves:
        current_moves = current_moves.mapped('move_to_ids.move_to_id')
        current_moves -= moves_to_recalculate
        moves_to_recalculate |= current_moves
```